# Multiple selects in stored procedure using union - Noob

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, union

I have searched for answers but find myself more confused. I am not as experienced - but with low staff - and just me creating reports - I have to create this.

Client has asked for a report that will return MTD answers on survey questions that are stored in 2 databases. Problem is - they want records that are attached to each submitted answer that are not a part of the survey. i.e. each respondent has a information regarding what type of phone they have, area they live in, model of phone and days of service. (these are not answers though)

Many of them are unique. (Models and Cities)

So for example I have created a stored procedure in SQL to pull into SSRS to display results.

But each one is a select and I am only getting the first result. I tried adding `UNION ALL` but it doesn't seem to let me group them when I do this. I get everything in one column, where as I need them in separate columns - horizontally ideally. But that may be asking too much.

Here is an example - perhaps there is a quicker way - this is a monstrous project - and my deadline is running short now - and I have tried so many things - and searching. Nothing left to do but ask for help.

So here is what I have -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST_WIRELESS_DISCO_SURVEY_RESULTS]
(
   @STARTDATE DATETIME,
   @ENDDATE DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT 
       a.CUSTOM17 as 'Make', COUNT(ISNULL(A.custom17, 0)) as 'Total Make'
   FROM GCI_SURVEYS as a
   JOIN GCI_Post_Survey_PreRepair_Master as b ON a.CustAcctNo = b.CustAcctNo
   WHERE b.Trans_Date between @STARTDATE and @ENDDATE
     AND a.i3_rowid = 'GCI_WRLSDISC_BSV'
     AND a.Q01 = 'no'
   GROUP BY  CUSTOM17

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 
       a.CUSTOM22 as 'Market', COUNT(ISNULL(a.CUSTOM22, 0)) as 'Total Market'
   FROM GCI_SURVEYS  as a
   JOIN GCI_Post_Survey_PreRepair_Master as b ON a.CustAcctNo = b.CustAcctNo
   WHERE b.Trans_Date between @STARTDATE  and @ENDDATE
     AND a.i3_rowid = 'GCI_WRLSDISC_BSV'
     AND a.Q01 = 'no'
   GROUP BY  a.CUSTOM22
```

Comment: can u show what result u get after this query

Comment: Try use join instead of union.

Comment: Could you give an example of that, please?

Comment: After this is run I get the following -

Comment: After this is run I get the following -  Sorry the columns are not lining up here (below)                                                          
Make Total Make
Apple    4
BLACKBERRY      4
COAM   11
LG           5
MOTOROLA        13
Nokia    3
Samsung              26
Verykool             7
Anchorage          38
Barrow 1
Bethel  10
Dillingham          3
Fairbanks            8
Juneau 2
Ketchikan            1
Kodiak  1
Kotzebue            1
Mat-Su 7
Nome Borough (minus Nome)  1
Wade Hampton                5

Answer (score 0):

In the **Question** you stated that you are fetching data from two **Database**

***return MTD answers on survey questions that are stored in 2 databases***

In you **SP** you are Selecting from the same the **DB**

Just add the **Database** Name in one of your `Select Query`

Comment: I apologize i misspoke - it is same database - I meant 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation, I would think that the top part of the union and the bottom contain the same surveys, just different parts?

I personally would load them into variable tables (or if alot of records, tempoary tables), and then join them together.

```
DECLARE @MakeQuestion TABLE
(
  survery_id INT --datatype
 ,make       VARCHAR(200) --replace with your own
 ,total_make INT
)

INSERT INTO @MakeQuestion
SELECT a.join_condition, a.CUSTOM17 as 'Make',COUNT(ISNULL(A.custom17,0)) as 'Total Make'
FROM GCI_SURVEYS as a
JOIN GCI_Post_Survey_PreRepair_Master as b
ON a.CustAcctNo = b.CustAcctNo
WHERE b.Trans_Date between @STARTDATE and @ENDDATE
AND a.i3_rowid = 'GCI_WRLSDISC_BSV'
AND a.Q01 = 'no'
GROUP BY  a.join_condition,CUSTOM17

DECLARE @MarketQuestion TABLE
(
  survery_id  INT -- datatype
 ,market        VARCHAR(200) --replace with your own
 ,total_market INT
)

Insert INTO @MarketQuestion
SELECT  a.join_condition, a.CUSTOM22 as 'Market',COUNT(ISNULL(a.CUSTOM22,0)) as 'Total Market'
FROM GCI_SURVEYS  as a
JOIN GCI_Post_Survey_PreRepair_Master as b
ON a.CustAcctNo = b.CustAcctNo
WHERE b.Trans_Date between @STARTDATE  and @ENDDATE
AND a.i3_rowid = 'GCI_WRLSDISC_BSV'
AND a.Q01 = 'no'
GROUP BY  a.CUSTOM22

SELECT *
FROM @MakeQuestion Make
INNER JOIN @MarketQuestion Market ON Make.survey_id = Market.survery_id
```

Please let me know if i misunderstood.

Comment: Oh wow, ok I will give this a go and see what happens.Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to get all of the selects to create separate columns? Like a wrapper? I have tried examples but it keeps asking for scalar variable to be declared- Union just gives it in one column.